# Formatting Hard Drive in windows

Tags: hard-drive, formatting, format

What is the differences between quick format and normal format in windows?
I Just formatted my external Hard Drive by quick format and it took a minute to complete and then I just started formatting the hard drive by normal formatting and it is still going. It's about two and a half hour I started formatting.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302686/en-us

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302686

Comment: @joeqwerty Good timing!

Comment: and the same to you, Shane ;)

Comment: it's another question but I can not post it now(20 minutes for each post rule). I just heard that even after normal formatting, previous data is recoverable and the data should be 7 times overwritten to be unrecoverable. is it right?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. There are labs that can recover some or all data after a format. Are you worried about the NSA? Because if they cared about your data, they already got it via an exploit that you didn't know existed.

Comment: I'm not american and I don't live in america. I just wanted to know what exactly makes data unrecoverable and how!

Comment: The NSA's official brief is foreign nationals, so my point stands.

Comment: oh! that's awful...

Answer (score 0):

A full format carries out analysis of the drive, i.e.: locating duff sectors.

Comment: Only incidentally, by writing to every address on the drive.  It does not intentionally run any tests or report on the results by itself.

Comment: @FalconMomot You mean it analyses by writing to every address on the drive? I didn't get your comment

Comment: In a roundabout way, yes.  A "full" format zeros every byte.  When this happens, the drive's firmware will incidentally detect and mark as bad those sectors which can't be zeroed, so afterward the SMART status will be accurate.  The distinction is that `format` isn't actually testing anything; it's just writing zeroes.  But, then, that's also kind of how `chkdsk` works too (except that it does it in more detail and checks what is happening while it goes).